# Why doesn't CORS work in ASP.NET Core 3 Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I try to write simple Web Api based on ASP.NET Core 3. But I have problem with CORS policy. That's my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(
            options => options.WithOrigins("http://myorigin.com").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

That's how I call to it from front-end:

```
function api_call()
    {
        var form = document.forms["userForm"];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://myorigin.com:8080/access",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function (worker) {
                form.elements["result"].value = worker;
            },
            error: function (jxqr, error, status) {
                console.log(jxqr);
                if(jxqr.responseText===""){
                    form.elements["result"].value = jxqr.statusText;
                }
                else{
                    var response = JSON.parse(jxqr.responseText);
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response['Auth']) {
                        $.each(response['Auth'], function (index, item) {
                            form.elements["result"].value = item;
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

But this function doesn't get access to API. It returns the message that request was blocked by CORS policy:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to use CORS in different ways by the different articles. I also tried to add manual CORS middlewares but the result it the same.
My Web Api is hosted on Ubuntu and runs by kestrel service without mistakes. Also when i run it locally in Visual studio and write in my JS function path to localhost (url: "http://localhost:56597/access") it calls to API and gets the response from it successfully.

What is my mistake? My front-end and Web Api are located on the same host but listen to different ports.

Comment: I guess your calling web application isn't running on port 80. Default ports for IIS Express are randomly set when you create the project for the first time and kestrel hosting usually defaults to 5000/5001. You have nothing specified, which means port 80. Different ports are different origins (except in old Internet Explorer browsers who threat it as same origin)

Comment: @tseng I set Apache with forwarding requests from 8080 to 5000 which is used by kestrel and my API.

Comment: Yea, but you have `.WithOrigins("http://myorigin.com")` in your code, which imply port 80 (thats the default http port). 80 != 8080

Comment: @tseng Yes, because I sending requests from front-end which is located on default 80 port to 8080 listened by apache to forward on api. So i need to resolve my origin with default port in CORS because api gets requests from it.
Anyway now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded my mistakes. I forgot to add this in my Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I read in one article that it is needed in my case.
Also there were mistakes in my Apache config for Web Api. I had parameters like that:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
```

But they should be like that:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Now my Web Api is working and there are no problems with CORS.

Comment: Depends on where you add auth. Generally, Auth should be added after Cors middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure. If you add .UseAuth before Cors this may cause issue for unauthenticated users or preflights